# Cannot enable 4K resolution on external monitor

Tags: manjaro, xrandr, laptop, resolution, hdmi

I have a laptop - Toshiba Satellite L640-1157U i3-380M - with a HDMI port that probably supports 4K@30HZ.

I also have an external monitor that definitely supports 4K@30HZ (doing well under win10 environment).

The laptop is installed with manjaro 21.3.7, and its default resolution on HDMI-0 is 1920x1080.

```
xrandr                                                                                         ✔ 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1280x720      59.97  
   1152x768      59.95  
   1024x768      59.95  
   800x600       59.96  
   848x480       59.94  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1096mm x 616mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  3840x2160_30.00 (0x70e) 338.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4080 end 4488 total 5136 skew    0 clock  65.96KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2200           clock  29.98Hz
```

So I type the following commands to get 3840x2160@30HZ.

```
cvt 3840 2160 30                                                                              
# 3840x2160 29.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 65.96 kHz; pclk: 338.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_30.00"  338.75  3840 4080 4488 5136  2160 2163 2168 2200 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_30.00"  338.75  3840 4080 4488 5136  2160 2163 2168 2200 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 3840x2160_30.00                                                       
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160_30.00
```

Unfortunately, external monitor just go blank (no signal).

```
xrandr                                                                                    
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5206 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1280x720      59.97  
   1152x768      59.95  
   1024x768      59.95  
   800x600       59.96  
   848x480       59.94  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1096mm x 616mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   3840x2160_30.00  29.98* 
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

What else I can do?

Comment: What makes you think that chip can do 4K? A quick search suggests it is only capable of HD.

Comment: @Bib I have a much older Intel iGPU, HD520, which does support 4K. Your reply is terribly wrong.

Comment: First, try kernel 6.0.3, if it still doesn't work for you, file a bug report: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov HD520 came out in 2015, the i3-380M came out in 2010. Your chip is 5 years newer than the op's. Perhaps you meant someother gpu.

Comment: @Bib This laptop is manufactured at 2010, whereas HDMI 1.4, which support 4K, came out at 2019.

Comment: @AndyLin HDMI 1.4 came out in 2009 and 1.4a in 2010, not 2019. That however matters little as to whether the i3-380M supports 4K given that supported chipsets tend to be a year or two behind the releasing of the spec.

Comment: The Nvidia GeForce 600 series released in 2012 would appear to be the first nvidia to support 1,4a. The first ATI to support 4K also came out in 2012.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, I thought it was a Tiger Lake Intel CPU. On a second reading I've no idea what the 1157U is. Never heard of this CPU before. The Intel website doesn't know about it at all: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/search.html?_charset_=UTF-8&q=1157U

Comment: That was difficult to find but GMA HD on this CPU ostensibly supports HDMI 1.3a, thus it must support 4K@30Hz: https://bit-tech.net/reviews/tech/graphics/intel-gma-hd-graphics-performance/1/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Gen5

Comment: The OP: Please upload the Xorg.log somewhere, e.g. pastebin.com

Comment: Again an HDMI 1.3a confirmation: https://www.engadget.com/apple-ipad-pro-2022-preview-m2-chip-130006105.html https://hothardware.com/reviews/intel-arrandale-core-i5-and-core-i3-mobile-unveiled?page=3 and this page specifically states that 4K@30Hz is possible: https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_HD_Graphics

Comment: There's a 99.999% chance Intel developers will **not** even attempt to fix this even if this is possible. No one at Intel has access to these old CPUs/GPUs. You really should consider buying a new laptop with HDMI 2.0 support - that will allow 4K@60Hz. Even if you enable 4K@24Hz for your laptop, you won't get smooth 24Hz, it will be a complete stutter mess. This iGPU is simply too feeble to drive this amount of pixels. It will most likely struggle even with 1440p output.

Comment: Many laptop OEMs have often cheaped out on the HDMI port, so for instance even when the iGPU supports a certain HDMI level, the laptop cannot physically use this level.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have no idea why you posted something about an ipad, but the others do not suggest anything capable of 4K30Hz with this cpu. The max official resolution for 1.3a was 2560x1600p.

Comment: HDMI 1.3 can output 4K: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_standard_video  IPAD - was a wrong link for engadget. They change the link when you scroll the page. I've already lost the source article URL but it was on engadget. People are so anal, FML. 30 seconds later.  OK, here's the proper URL: https://www.engadget.com/2010-01-25-intel-gma-hd-graphics-review-deems-them-excellent-for-video-med.html I'm SO F_CKING SORRY. *Noting full bitstreaming (our HD editors inform us that's a big deal), Blu-ray with picture-in-picture, and HDMI 1.3a support*